# changing tuples of a table through the view in Oracle Database

Tags: oracle

I am new to views in SQL: I have a table named as `Courses(dept_code, course#, title, credits, deptname)` I am supposed to create a view "CSCourses(CSCourses logically contains only CS courses from Courses)" which consists of only CS courses. I used the following command:

```
create view CSCourses
    as select *
    from Courses
    where dept_code = 'CS';
```

Now I have to do two more tasks which are as follows:

1. Try to insert a tuple into, delete a tuple from, and update a value of Courses through CSCourses.
2. Try to insert a new math course into Course via CSCourses. Note that this new course does not logically belong to CSCourses. Report whether you succeeded.

NOTE: I am using Oracle Database through command line interface.

If someone has any ideas then please do share.

Comment: And what's stopping you from proceeding further?

Comment: I don't know the concept. If you can tell me the concept then I can move further.

Comment: This is a school assignment, I guess. You just have to issue the commands to the database and see what it happens: the assignment itself is guiding you telling you exactly, step by step what you have to do: create the table, create the view (and it gives you the exact command you have to issue), insert a row in the table, update it indirectly by the view, insert a new row in the view. So... where is the problem? What do you mean by "I don't know the concept"? which concept? you don't know what a table is? what a view is? what a database is? you don't know how to issue sql cmds by command line?

Comment: The term you are looking for is "updatable view" - a simple view like that is by default updatable in Oracle. See e.g. here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/CREATE-VIEW.html#GUID-61D2D2B4-DACC-4C7C-89EB-7E50D9594D30

Comment: Thank you  @a_horse_with_no_name. You gave me what I need. Thanks a lot.